# Simplifying to remove all imaginary numbers

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have a purely real function (`spec[w]`, where `Im[spec[w]]=0`), found through

```
f[x_] = Piecewise[{{2 (R^2 - x^2)/R, Abs[x] <= R}, {0, True}}];
F[w_] = FourierTransform[Exp[-I*f[x]], x, w, Assumptions -> {R > 0, w \[Element] Reals}];
spec[w_] = Abs[F[w]]^2
```

Now, `spec[w]` is very ugly, even after calls to `FullSimplify` and `ExpToTrig`. For my own analysis, I've been trying to simplify the complex exponentials, removing imaginary numbers, etc. Is there a way to make Mathematica do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You do not have a function but a distribution with DiracDelta. ,  Further, apart from the DiracDelta, the rest is a full blown complex function, the result of spec is only real because you are using "Abs". Therefore, what do you expect from "Simplify"?

Comment: I think no chance because `F[w]` includes `Erfi[(1/4 + I/4) Sqrt[R] (4 + w)] ` =$\text{erfi}\left(\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{i}{4}\right) \sqrt{R} (w+4)\right)$ and similar ones badly handled by `Re` and `Im`.

Comment: In order to avoid `DiracDelta` under the modulus one may consider `FourierTransform[Exp[-I*f[x]]-1, x, w, Assumptions -> {R > 0, w \[Element] Reals}]` and work with it to remove the imaginary unit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
spec[w_] = Conjugate[F[w]]F[w] //ComplexExpand
```

but further assumptions concerning the parameters might be necessary!

Comment: Bad Idea: `F[w]` includes `Erfi[(1/4 + I/4) Sqrt[R] (4 + w)]` ==$\text{erfi}\left(\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{i}{4}\right) \sqrt{R} (w+4)\right)$ and similar ones badly handled by `Re` and `Im`.

Comment: ??? `Plot3D[ReIm[Erfi[(1/4 + I/4) Sqrt[R] (4 + w)]], {R, 0, 10}, {w, -1, 
  1}, PlotRange -> All]` evaluates without any problems!

Comment: This is another matter. Did you try to remove `I` from `Re[Erfi[(1/4 + I/4) Sqrt[R] (4 + w)]]` or `Im[Erfi[(1/4 + I/4) Sqrt[R] (4 + w)]]`  or `Abs[Erfi[(1/4 + I/4) Sqrt[R] (4 + w)]]`as OP requests?